# Creating a menu overlay in Xamarin Forms

Tags: forms, menu, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm relatvively new to xaml and xamarin forms. So far, I find it pretty powerful but my lack of experience and inability to find some samples of what I'm trying to do is bringing me here.

So I have a listview, when "tapping" the item, I would like to have a "popup" listing me available options (maybe having the options in an other listview).

What would be the best approach, either in code or xaml, to get a control to show on top a current listview and allow user to select an option?

The challenge is obviously not to reacting to selecting an option (I know how to do that). The challenge is to have a control appearing on top of another control until it is dismissed, or clicked outside. I know there is the picker control that does something a little similar but it doesn't offer control on the content as well as positioning (unless I missed something).

My listview, over which I want the list of options to appear, is inside a stack layout, that is inside a simple content page.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I might be able to do it with pushModalAsync if I can control the size and position of my modal, and still see the page underneath. Is that possible?

Comment: @ user1428857 In my project, I have done exactly similar task, showing menu on tap of ListView item with the help of DisplayActionSheet. I used code for my layout, because we have more control in code than xaml, since in code getting individual listview item id is easy than xaml. I don't see any problem using DisplayActionSheet for this, unless you have less number of menu items (say within 5 or 6).

Comment: @Subha, I suppose the DisplayActionSheet would work although I haven't tried yet. If my recollection is right, this is having some limitation though. You can't really style the DisplayActionSheet. It is simply a list of button. Also, it is returning you the text of the button, which is not very good in a translatable application.

Answer (score 2):

To make one control appearing on top of another control, you can place both of them in the grid:

```
<Grid>
    <StackLayout x:Name="YourListViewStackLayout">
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout x:Name="SomeAnotherControll" IsVisible="false">
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

So when you change the visibility of "SomeAnotherControll" it will cover "YourListViewStackLayout".

Comment: In this case, it will hide the entire control underneath. I would like my other control to appear like a contextual menu so that the user can see the menu pertain to a specific item in the list underneath.

Comment: It won't hide the entire control underneath if you place it in a BoxView with an opacity of say 50%. It will look like a pop-up, while shading out the form underneath

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to create your own pop-up with the help of custom controls and renderers

How to do that is described in the following post:
[custom pop-ups](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21413/can-i-use-customviewrenders-in-popups-actionsheets-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

I've just added this functionality to the Forms9Patch library in the form of the `Forms9Patch.ModalPopup` and `Forms9Patch.BubblePopup` elements.

For your use case, you would use the `Selected` event of your ListView and set the `Target` property of `Forms9Patch.BubblePopup` to a `Xamarin.Forms.View` element of your ListView.

You can learn more at http://Forms9Patch.com or at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/185332/#Comment_185332.

[GIF of Modal Popup http://buildcalc.com/forms9patch/Images/Modal-iOS.gif](http://buildcalc.com/forms9patch/Images/Modal-iOS.gif)

[GIF of Bubble Popup on iPhone http://buildcalc.com/forms9patch/Images/Bubble-iOS.gif](http://buildcalc.com/forms9patch/Images/Bubble-iOS.gif)

[GIF of Bubble Popup on Android http://buildcalc.com/forms9patch/Images/Bubble-droid.gif](http://buildcalc.com/forms9patch/Images/Bubble-droid.gif)